# Let$\ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{ \ln n}{f(n)}=1$. If$\ a,b,c$ are natural, can we have$\ a^{b+c \ln n}\sim a^{c f(n)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I shall note that$\ n$ as well goes through the natural numbers and that$\ f(n)$ is rational for any$\ n$. Also, I'm obviously excluding$\ a=1$. I'm inclined to think my claim is not possible because$\ b+c \ln n$ is always transcendental, while$\ b f(n)$ is always rational. I'm trying to prove it, though not having a too good time. I'd like to read some answer.

Comment: Is setting $a=1$ cheating?

Comment: @Meelo Yup. Should I have specified it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $f(n)$ constant does not work. Moreover
 for any non constant polinomial function it holds $\log n/ f(n)\to 0$, so no polinomial function $f$ satisfies $a^{b+c\log n} \sim a^{cf(n)}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Might I ask you what happens if$\ f$ is not polynomial and is asymptotically equal to$\ \log$ (just made the edit)?

Comment: Even if $f(n)/\log n\to 1$ is not sufficient: let $f(n)=\log n+\log\log n +c_n$ (where $c_n$ is chosen only to ensure that $f(n)$ is rational, and $c_n\to 0$), you have $a^{b+c\log n}/a^{cf(n)}=a^{b-c(\log(\log n)-c_n)}$.

Comment: But is my claim never possible? As I'm reading it now, doesn't your comment deal with a particular$\ f$? To generalize, tell me if this is correct: we consider$\ f(n)= \log n + c_n$ (where$\ c_n$ is chosen in the same way as before, but it doesn't tend to$\ 0$ as$\ n \to \infty$; at least, I would see this like a loss of generality, if it isn't necessary for some reason. And I think it isn't, while it is necessary to let$\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c_n}{\log n}=0$.), resulting in$\ a^{b+c \log n} / a^{c f(n)} = a^{b+c \times c_n }$. Now, recalling that$\ \log n + c_n$ is rational, we see...

Comment: ...that$\ c_n$ must be irrational, hence, so must be$\ c \times c_n$ and finally$\ b + c \times c_n$. We obviously would have reached the same conclusion if we had chosen$\ f(n)= \log n - c_n$: with the known conditions, we can't possibly have$\ \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{b+c \log n} / a^{c f(n)} =1$.

Correct?

Comment: Add "I would be very grateful and give you Best Answer if you confirmed this" somewhere in the last comments :v

Comment: your claim is possible with careful choice of $c_n$: with $f(n)=\log n +c_n$, you get $a^{b+c\log n}/a^{cf(n)}=a^{b-c c_n}$, and while $b\neq cc_n$ for any $n$ (being $b$ rational but $cc_n$ irrational), you can have $b-cc_n\to 0$ (any rational can be written as limit of sequence of irrationals), hence $a^{b-cc_n}\to 1$.

Comment: So my claim is possibile if and only if$\ c \times c_n \to b$, right? A possibility that we would exclude by letting$\ c f(n) \to b$, correct?

Comment: minor correction: *possible

Comment: Correct, if $f(n)=\log n+c_n$, claim holds if and only with $cc_n\to b$. However this is possible, we do not really let $cf(n)\to b$ (note that f(n) must contain something asymptotic to $\log n$, otherwise there is no way to cancel the $c\log n$ from the first term).

Comment: Sure. But, and this should be my last question (sounds kinda epic), suppose$\ c f(n) \to b$. Then the claim is impossible?

Comment: Supposing $c f(n)\to b$ gives $a^{cf(n)}\to a^b$, while $a^{b+c\log n}\to +\infty$, so you can't have $a^{b+c\log n}\sim a^{cf(n)}$

Comment: Even easier, yeah. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.